# JQuery - Pause animation / add a next button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a CodePen of what I've created (with the help of other sources) and everything looks great. I want the ability to click on the text (or the page) and pause the JQuery loop. As well as the ability to click it again to resume it. [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/L13C/pen/jOOGaLr)

If that's too hard, I would like to look at the Next button so I can manually toggle to the next line, as well as a manual toggle button to the main line of `<li>#SSBASKETBALL&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;SUMMERSERIES.NZ</li>`

The button needs to be at the bottom further down as it's part of OBS's Browser tool.

If anyone could help me out with this, please feel free. It does the job at the moment, but I would really like to incorporate it more professionally and have more control over it. Cheers!

```js
(function($) {
  $.simpleTicker = function(element, options) {
    var defaults = {
      speed: 800,
      delay: 10000,
      easing: 'swing',
      effectType: 'fade'
    }
    var param = {
      'ul': '',
      'li': '',
      'initList': '',
      'ulWidth': '',
      'liHeight': '',
      'tickerHook': 'tickerHook',
      'effect': {}
    }

    var plugin = this;
    plugin.settings = {}
    var $element = $(element),
      element = element;

    plugin.init = function() {
      plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      param.ul = element.children('ul');
      param.li = element.find('li');
      param.initList = element.find('li:first');
      param.ulWidth = param.ul.width();
      param.liHeight = param.li.height();

      element.css({
        height: (param.liHeight)
      });
      param.li.css({
        top: '0',
        left: '0',
        position: 'absolute'
      });


      switch (plugin.settings.effectType) {
        case 'fade':
          plugin.effect.fade();
          break;
        case 'roll':
          plugin.effect.roll();
          break;
        case 'slide':
          plugin.effect.slide();
          break;
      }
      plugin.effect.exec();
    }

    plugin.effect = {};
    plugin.effect.exec = function() {
      param.initList.css(param.effect.init.css)
        .animate(param.effect.init.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
        .addClass(param.tickerHook);
      setInterval(function() {
        element.find('.' + param.tickerHook)
          .animate(param.effect.start.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
          .next()
          .css(param.effect.next.css)
          .animate(param.effect.next.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
          .addClass(param.tickerHook)
          .end()
          .appendTo(param.ul)
          .css(param.effect.end.css)
          .removeClass(param.tickerHook);
      }, plugin.settings.delay);
    }

    plugin.effect.fade = function() {
      param.effect = {
        'init': {
          'css': {
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0'
          },
          'animate': {
            opacity: '1',
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        },
        'start': {
          'animate': {
            opacity: '0'
          }
        },
        'next': {
          'css': {
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0',
            zIndex: '99'
          },
          'animate': {
            opacity: '1'
          }
        },
        'end': {
          'css': {
            display: 'none',
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    plugin.effect.roll = function() {
      param.effect = {
        'init': {
          'css': {
            top: '-3em',
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0'
          },
          'animate': {
            top: '0',
            opacity: '1',
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        },
        'start': {
          'animate': {
            top: '3em',
            opacity: '0'
          }
        },
        'next': {
          'css': {
            top: '-3em',
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0',
            zIndex: '99'
          },
          'animate': {
            top: '0',
            opacity: '1'
          }
        },
        'end': {
          'css': {
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    plugin.effect.slide = function() {
      param.effect = {
        'init': {
          'css': {
            left: (-(200)),
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0'
          },
          'animate': {
            left: '0',
            opacity: '1',
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        },
        'start': {
          'animate': {
            left: (200),
            opacity: '0'
          }
        },
        'next': {
          'css': {
            left: (param.ulWidth),
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '0',
            zIndex: '99'
          },
          'animate': {
            left: '0',
            opacity: '1'
          }
        },
        'end': {
          'css': {
            zIndex: '98'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    plugin.init();
  }

  $.fn.simpleTicker = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (undefined == $(this).data('simpleTicker')) {
        var plugin = new $.simpleTiecker(this, options);
        $(this).data('simpleTicker', plugin);
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $.simpleTicker($('#js-ticker-fade'), {
    'effectType': 'fade'
  });
  $.simpleTicker($('#js-ticker-roll'), {
    'effectType': 'roll'
  });
  $.simpleTicker($('#js-ticker-slide'), {
    'effectType': 'slide'
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "DharmaGothicEW01-Light";
  src: url("https:https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.eot");
  src: url("https:https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.woff") format("woff"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/dcc1a03cbbd06fea7e48d65ff78624ef.svg#DharmaGothicEW01-Light") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "DharmaGothicEW01-Bold";
  src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.eot");
  src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.woff") format("woff"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/5c5772b491b3e1c39beb61efcd6824f7.svg#DharmaGothicEW01-Bold") format("svg");
}

* {
  font-size: 32px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: DharmaGothicEW01-Light;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.hvhbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  background: #fe3249;
  text-align: center;
}

.simple-ticker {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.simple-ticker ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.simple-ticker ul li {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery simple news ticker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->


  <section>
    <div class="simple-ticker" id="js-ticker-roll">
      <ul>
        <li>#SSBASKETBALL&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;SUMMERSERIES.NZ</li>
        <li>THE SUMMER SERIES 20:&nbsp;<span style="background: #979797; color: #fff;">&nbsp;HUTT VALLEY </span>&ensp;VS&ensp;<span style="background: #0053a3; color: #fff;">&nbsp;UPPER HUTT&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li>THE SUMMMER SERIES IS PROUDLY SUPPORTED BY TRIPLE THREAT</li>
        <li><span style="background: #0053a3; color: #fff">&nbsp;UHC </span>&nbsp;RJ WICHMAN&emsp;13 PTS</li>
        <li><span style="background: #979797; color: #fff;">&nbsp;HVH </span>&ensp;25% [1/4]&emsp;&emsp;3PT PERCENTAGE&emsp;&emsp;20% [1/5]&ensp;<span style="background: #0053a3; color: #fff;">&nbsp;UHC&nbsp;</span></li>
        <!-- <li>NEXT UP:&nbsp;<span style="background: #fb1414; color: #fff;">&nbsp;SACRED HEART </span>&ensp;VS&ensp;<span style="background: #fff200; color: #000;">&nbsp;WELLINGTON EAST&nbsp;</span></li> -->



      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What occures to me is to add a function to simpleticker called stop and a property called stopped, the stop function just quit the animation and fixes the actual li and changes stopped value, when user clicks button fires stop if is not stopped and calls animation if is stopped

Comment: I’ll be honest, I have no clue how to do this. Any help? Thanks!